# R Shiny reactivity error, how can I fix it?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

i have the following shiny application:
Dataset:(https://www.kaggle.com/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings)

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui = navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),"Video Games Dashboard",
                tabPanel("Dashboard",
                         sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                                 selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                                         label = "Choose a dataset:",
                                         choices = colnames(data)),
                             
                         ),
                         mainPanel(
                             plotOutput(outputId = "ggPlot"),
                             plotOutput(outputId = "ggPlot2"),
                             
                         )
                     )
            ),
            tabPanel("Summary",
            )
)
server <- function(input, output) {


output$ggPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot ( data=data,aes(x=Global_Sales, y=input$dataset)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity" ,fill="steelblue") +
        coord_flip() +
        theme_minimal()
})

output$ggPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot ( data=data,aes(x=Global_Sales, y=Platform)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity" ,fill="steelblue") +
        
        theme_minimal()
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

As you can see I want to do the same in the first plot("ggPlot") like in the second plot("ggPlot2") just that the first plot is reactive and you can select every column of the datatable to display it in the plot.
However, I get this message all the time:

**Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.**

Does anybody know how to fix this? Is this approach even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the first plot is the one you expect, with a single bar ? If you want to set `y` to the variable whose name is `input$dataset` you can do `aes_string(x="Global_Sales", y=input$dataset)`. In your code, `y` is not set to a variable of the data, because `input$dataset` is a string.

Comment: Hi Stéphane when I write  aes_string as you sad it works! Thank you! Why exactly is input$dataset a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning appears when there's a single item on one of the two axes - see [this shiny issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2673).

But your code does not produce the plot you expect: `input$dataset` is the *name* of a column of the data, hence it is a string, and then when you do `aes(x = Global_Sales, y = input$dataset)`, the `y` argument of `aes` is not set to a variable of the data, it is set to a string. So you have a single item on the y-axis, hence the warning.

To set the arguments of `aes` to some variables of the data when you have the names of these variables, you can use `aes_string`:

```
aes_string(x = "Global_Sales", y = input$dataset)
```